# backspace key has stopped working in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I've just encountered an extremely frustrating problem in VS 2017 Pro. Backspace is completely non-functional in the editor.

I've tried some Googling, but the only references I've found to this kind of problem are very old, and in most cases, various other keys were effected, enter, arrows etc. For me it's only backspace.

I should add, the key is definitely ok, and works fine in all other applications.

I've obviously tried restarting Visual Studio, and Windows, to no effect.

As far as I'm aware there has been no recent windows or VS updates. I've been using VS 2017 without any problems for a few weeks now. This has only just happened this morning.

Does anyone have any idea what could cause this, or what I could try to do to fix it?

Comment: Must often it appears when a VS dialog box is opened in background and you're ignoring it by working in the editor.  Closing the dialog box will do the trick.

Comment: @ArnaudF. Thanks for the comment. Unfortunately this isn't the problem. There is no dialog. As I mentioned it is only backspace that's effected. All other keys work fine.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm not sure what caused VS to get messed up, but I was able to eventually solve it by resetting the environment.

Tools -> Import and Export Settings -> Reset All Settings

Just in case it's helpful to anyone else.

Comment: "Reset". The quintessential action.

Comment: Just reinstall Windows or even better: switch all parts in your PC. jk xD

Answer (score 4):

There is another way - The command is Edit.DeleteBackwards and just map that to your Backspace key for the Text Editor.

Comment: No key re-mapping required. VS just needed to be reset. This answer could confuse people into trying to fix faults in VS, by unnecessarily remapping keys.

Comment: True, but if you have quite a few custom mappings, like I do, your solution means I need to remap all of my custom maps after resetting.

Comment: Key remapping is a better solution than resetting the whole Visual Studio. I have configured tenths if not hundreds of tiny little options in Visual Studio over the years. I backup my settings from time to time for when I have to reinstall a system or Visual Studio. I just set a few new keyboard shortcuts and resetting settings would mean pretty much mean that I have to restore my backup settings from a few weeks ago, and I don't want to set all these settings again.